# Projective transformation at infinity

Tags: projective-geometry

Suppose I have the line $2x+3y+w=0$ which contains the point
$[1, -1, 1]$. After projective transformation given by multiplying by a matrix, it goes to infinite point $[1, -1, 0]$ which lies on the line $x+y+w =0$ at infinity. But the line at infinity is the line $w=0$ which contains the infinite point $[1, -1, 0]$, and we know that the ideal line (the line at infinity) is just the collection of ideal points (points at infinity).

My first question is that is it possible that $x+y+w =0$ is also treated as the ideal line since it contains the ideal point $[1, -1, 0]$?

My second question is that some websites say that in the projective plane, $w=0$ is the equation of a plane and some say that it is the equation of a line. Which one is right?

My final question is that on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_geometry#Affine_space), it says that affine space is the complement of the hyperplane at infinity in the projective plane. But my understanding is that they should write the complement of the line at infinity (or $w=0$). Why did they write the hyperplane at infinity instead of the line at infinity?

Comment: You wrote, "affine plane is complement of hyperplane at infinity in projective plane", but in Wikipedia it is a projective *space*.

Comment: @David K corrected..

Comment: I was actually thinking of the second "plane" in the quote, not the first "plane," but indeed they both are "space" in Wikipedia. And while the projective *plane* has a single line at infinity, projective *space* of more than two dimensions has more than just a line at infinity. The correct generic term for the collection of all points at infinity in a projective space of $n$ dimensions is hyperplane. If the space has just two dimensions (if it is a projective plane) then the particular type of hyperplane that you find at infinity is a line.

Comment: @David K thanks... Could you provide full answer with other questions...

Comment: For someone to post a regular answer the question must be reopened. It might draw positive attention to the question if the first paragraph were carefully edited; right now, without being able to read your mind, it is difficult to see how to fix all the grammar errors so that it (1) actually says something and (2) says what you intended. Regarding "which book is correct", I suspect both are correct within the context of what was being discussed on the page where each statement occurred. More exact citations of the two books might help (title, author, edition, page number).

Comment: @David K you want to say that for P^2 , W=0 is line and for higher dimensional hyperplane it should be plane..

Comment: I have edited your question to try to make it clearer, and I have voted to reopen. Please let me know if I accidentally changed the meaning of anything you intended to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line $x + y + w = 0$ is not the line at infinity; the line at infinity is $w = 0$. You seem to think that because the point $[1, -1, 0]$ is on the line at infinity and the line $x + y + w = 0$, then the two lines must be the same; that is not the case. The line $x + y + w = 0$ contains a point at infinity, but it does not contain all of them (for example, $[1, 0, 0]$), whereas the line at infinity does. In fact, every line $ax + by + cz = 0$ (other than the line at infinity), intersects the line at infinity in exactly one point, namely $[b, -a, 0]$.

In the projective *plane*, the equation $w = 0$ is the *line* at infinity. However, one can also form $n$-dimensional projective *space*, in which case the equation $w = 0$ defines the *hyperplane* at infinity. There is no contradiction here; when $n = 2$, the two notions coincide, i.e. $2$-dimensional projective space is the projective plane, and a hyperplane in the projective plane is a line.

Similarly, the complement of the *line* at infinity of the projective *plane* is the affine *plane*. On the other hand, the complement of the *hyperplane* at infinity of $n$-dimensional projective *space* is the $n$-dimensional affine *space*. Again, when $n = 2$, the two notions coincide, i.e. the $2$-dimensional affine space is the affine plane.

Comment: @ MichaelAlbanese in David K  answer  he wrote check this.."A projective plane has only one ideal line, so no, you cannot have an ideal line defined by w=0 and also have an ideal line defined by x+y+w=0". it needs edit or not  .. . I seem  ideal line W=0 and not ideal line x+y+W =0

Comment: What David K wrote is correct: there is only one ideal line, so $w = 0$ and $x + y + w = 0$ cannot both be ideal lines.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, if you have a projective plane and have identified the ideal points in an appropriate way, *every* line contains at least one ideal point. The difference between the ideal line and every other line is that every other line contains **exactly one** ideal point (and no others), whereas **every** point on the ideal line is an ideal point.

A projective plane has only one ideal line, so no, you cannot have an ideal line defined by $w = 0$ and also have an ideal line defined by $x + y + w = 0.$

Regarding whether $w = 0$ is the equation of a line, a plane, or something else, it is highly dependent on context. Without going to the specific place on the specific page of the specific website where a statement was made that $w = 0$ is the equation of something, it is impossible to say whether the statement was correct.
It is as if a friend of yours told you he read on a website somewhere that the author's car was blue, and he asks you if it was true that the car is blue.
How would you know? You can't know unless your friend tells you where to find the statement on the website. Otherwise it could be any car, of practically any color.

When discussing geometry and projective geometry, even the meanings of apparently simple words are highly context-dependent. We might be discussing four-dimensional Euclidean space one day, within which we identify various subsets of points that form one-dimensional lines, two-dimensional planes, and three-dimensional hyperplanes.
But in a different conversation the word "hyperplane" might mean any of those things--it could have three dimensions, or two, or one.

The meaning of "hyperplane" on the linked Wikipedia page is one of those
any-number-of-dimensions hyperplanes,
not a necessarily-three-or-more-dimensional kind of hyperplane.
It could be a line, and if the projective space under discussion
is a projective **plane**, the hyperplane at infinity **is** a line.

It is also possible that someone explaining projective geometry might use
three-dimensional Euclidean space with Cartesian coordinates $x,y,w$
in order to model a two-dimensional projective plane.
In one such model, each line through the origin of the three-dimensional
Euclidean space is declared to be a point of the projective plane.
The equation $w = 0$ describes a plane in the Euclidean space
which also contains all the ideal points of the projective plane
and therefore represents the ideal line of the projective plane.
Therefore when we speak of the object defined by $w = 0$ in this particular model of a projective space,
we might be referring to the line (of the projective plane) defined by this equation **or** the plane (of the Euclidean space) defined by this equation.
And in some contexts we might mean both things at the same time, since that plane is a model of that line.

All of this may be confusing if you are just getting introduced to projective geometry. It's fine not to consider projective spaces other than projective planes or to identify points in a projective plane with lines in a Euclidean space.
But if you don't want to consider such things, you had better ignore websites that do consider such things, because the only way to make sense of what they are saying is to consider the possible dimensions and models that they are considering.

Comment: I never said $[0,0,0]$ was a point in the projective plane. A **line through $(0,0,0)$** (ordinary Cartesian coordinates, not homogeneous $[\,]$ coordinates!) is a "point" in a **model** of the projective plane. It takes an entire **line** in the model to model just one **point** of the projective plane, and it takes an entire plane in the model to model just one line of the projective plane.

Comment: If I have point in Euclidean space( a,b, k)  then it's model in projective plane P ^2 is (a/k, b/k, 1)

Comment: That's not a model. You cannot model all points of a three-dimensional Euclidean space using points of a two-dimensional projective plane. If $[a/k/b/k,1]$ is your model of $(a,b,k),$ what's your model of $(2a,2b,2k)$, which is a distinct point from $(a,b,k)$ in the space?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand "model".. Please give one example..

Comment: I gave an example. What you may not understand is that a "point" in any geometry is an abstract object. It has no physical meaning. All we really need to know about it is how it interacts with other objects in its geometry. We can imagine how the points look, perhaps draw pictures of them on paper, but that is not what really defines the geometry; it is just a helpful visualization. A model of the geometry is any collection of objects that fit the necessary definitions. Those objects could be lists of numbers (coordinates), or they could be different objects from a different geometry.

Comment: What does the meaning of "A line through (0,0,0) (ordinary Cartesian coordinates, not homogeneous [] coordinates!) is a "point" in a model of the projective plane"... Please elaborate in simple words..

Comment: See [this page](https://www.open.edu/openlearn/science-maths-technology/mathematics-statistics/surfaces/content-section-3.3), the paragraph before figure 62, starting with "The geometric approach is to define the projective plane as the set of all infinite lines through the origin in Euclidean three-dimensional space".

Comment: I understand all things.. But not able to understand " It takes an entire line in the model to model just one point of the projective plane, and it takes an entire plane in the model to model just one line of the projective plane. "

Comment: Why (0, 0,0) is meaningless in projective plane  P^2?